# What's inside the Jail?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

There is a jail in Los Santos. I only know player cannot fly above it, and the carpark outside has a lot of jeeps to steal. But I never go into it.

Anyone dares to "visit" the jail?

Comment: There's no mission associated with the jail, as of yet. There might be some missions involving the jail in future DLC, but that's only speculation.

Comment: I want to parachute into the jail. LOL

Comment: Well, you can do that. You'll get a wanted level, though, but it is possible.

Comment: I think I'll be dead for sure.

Comment: Also I believe it is the setting for one of the GTA Online deathmatches or LTS missions.

Comment: A safe way to explore is to purchase the Rhino Tank from Cache & Carry and just drive through the front gate.  You're pretty much untouchable and can wander around with your 4 stars to your hearts content.  There's not much there though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, the only reasons one would want to "break in", would be for the [Show Off](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Show_Off) achievement, as one Stunt Jump will require you to land within the confines of said prison.

The Stunt Jump in question is best performed in a motorcycle, as you'll be less likely to crash into a building before landing, which would invalidate the jump. Landing inside the prison, or staying in its air space for too long will result in a lot of (un)wanted police attention.

Answer (score 5):

There's not much to see inside the prison. I used the cheat: High jump and Invincibility so I can jump over the fences and walk inside without dying but there's not much to see only guards shooting you and a prison van.